# Android NullPointerException when setting Dialogs background drawable

Tags: java, android

When setting my Dialogs background drawable, I am getting a warning **Method invocation 'setBackgroundDrawable' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'**. How would I go about preventing such an exception?

```
class UIManager {

    private Context context;
    private MapActivity activity;
    private Dialog dialog;

    UIManager(MapActivity activity, Context context) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.upload_dialog);

        /* THIS LINE */
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    void showUploadDialog() {
        dialog.show();
    }

    void dismissUploadDialog() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the exception by checking if `dialog.getWindow()` returned `null`. However in practise this should not ever happen because it will only return null if the activity it is bound to is not being shown.